# Ajax.ActionLink Button , 1 switch to disable all existing button in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my view I have 2 Ajax buttons and 1 switch.
here is my Ajax button :

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null, new AjaxOptions
                            {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "current",
                            LoadingElementId = "loading",
                            OnBegin = "ClearResults",
                            }, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1"}) 
 @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnCallAgain", null, new AjaxOptions
                            {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "current",
                            LoadingElementId = "loading",
                            OnBegin = "ClearResults",
                            }, new { @class = "Middle-callagain dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link2"})
```

And I want to use a switch to be able to disable these two buttons whenever I click the switch. Can anyone show me how? and if that is even possible?
Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to this.

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null, new AjaxOptions
       {
          HttpMethod = "GET",
          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
          UpdateTargetId = "current",
          LoadingElementId = "loading",
          OnBegin = "ClearResults",
      }, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1" , @style="display:none;"})


  @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnCallAgain", null, new AjaxOptions
     {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "current",
        LoadingElementId = "loading",
        OnBegin = "ClearResults",
     }, new { @class = "Middle-callagain dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link2", @style = "display:none;" })

<input type="button" class="switch" value="switch" isValue="1"/>

<script>

 $(document).on('click', '.switch', function () {

    var v = $(".switch").attr("isValue");
            if (v == 1) {
                $(".switch").attr("isValue","0");
                $(".dim").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".switch").attr("isValue", "1");
                $(".dim").hide();
            }
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, this is quite helpful but I want it as a switch not as a button.